# MySQL create a row containing the sum from existing rows

Tags: mysql

I need to create a new row within my table that contains the sum of existing rows and also delete the columns that were summed. Deleting is not a priority at this moment but certainly needed.

```
 t                   UL1     UL2    UL3     PL1       PL2   PL3        P     Q1      Q2  Q3  CosPhi1 CosPhi2 CosPhi3  i
2015-08-19 12:26:56 394.7   396.3   393.2   10.7    -180.9  46.5    -123.7  10.4    8.7 13.7    0.9      1.0   1.0    0
2015-08-19 12:26:55 394.8   396.4   393.4   10.6    -180.7  47.0    -123.2  12.0    8.8 13.9    0.8      1.0   1.0    0
2015-08-19 12:26:54 394.7   396.2   393.1   11.6    -180.5  46.5    -122.5   9.6    9.4 13.9    1.0      1.0   1.0    0
```

The table looks like this. Data is inserted every second and the table contains millions of rows. Since I dont need such high resolution for historical uses, I want to sum them together with an interval of 15 minutes and remove "old" data.
The columns that need to be summed are PL1, PL2, PL3 and P. t could be any time within the 15 minute interval.

I would like it to look something like this.

```
     t                      PL1    PL2   PL3     P    i
2015-08-19 12:26:56        33.0  -540.9  135.5 -375.7  0
```

I'm not sure how to make a query for this, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Didn't we do this already? Same answer as before. See normalisation.

Comment: A table has a fixed number of columns.  You cannot insert a new row that has different columns from the ones already in the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to mix two things (or maybe three) in a single process and this is dangerous, difficult to test and produces a lot of load on the table.

I suggest you a better, verified approach.

1. Create a new table to store the aggregate values. It can have the same structure as the existing table or a slightly different structure. Keep only the columns you want to aggregate, skip the other columns (`UL1`, `UL2`, `UL3` a.s.o).
2. Write a script that selects chunks of data from the big table (15 minutes at a time, for example) computes the aggregate values and insert them into the new table. It can run a SQL query to do that (using [`INSERT ... SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-select.html)) or it can do the computation on the application side, you choose what fits better your formula and the application's workflow. If possible, install the script as a cron job to run every 15 minutes or so. It can also remove the processed data in order to keep the old table slim or you can leave them, you decide.
3. Modify the application's code to use the new table to read the history data and the old table for recent data. Due to their different structures and the meaning of the data they store, the best way is to **not** use the existing code to read from it but write new code that maps to the structure of the new table.

Answer (score 0):

```
 insert into table(PL1,PL2,PL3,p,i)   
 select sum(PL1),SUM(PL2),sum(PL3),sum(p),sum(i)
```

You need to add a column that will store boolean. Something like `is_summation_row`, insert 1 into it whenever the sum is added so that later on you can delete the rows using

```
delete from tblName where is_summation_row=1
```

and then perform the insertion.